# `npm run watch` cant stop in laravel 5.4

Tags: npm, webpack, laravel-5.4

it's never stop unless i press ctrl+c. here mix.sass
mix.sass('resources/assets/frontend/sass/main.scss', 'public/assets/frontend/css/app.css');

WAIT  Compiling...                                                     2:07:13 PM
 95% emitting
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 404ms                                   2:07:14 PM
 WAIT  Compiling...                                                     2:07:14 PM
 95% emitting
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 268ms                                   2:07:14 PM
 WAIT  Compiling...                                                     2:07:14 PM
 95% emitting
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 268ms                                   2:07:15 PM
 WAIT  Compiling...                                                     2:07:15 PM
 95% emitting
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 265ms                                   2:07:15 PM
 WAIT  Compiling...                                                     2:07:15 PM

Comment: try `ctrl + z`, this should kill it

Comment: It doesn't.....

Comment: use `ctrl + c` ...

Comment: @اسماعیلزارع After that, you have to confirm with `Y`

Answer (score 4):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from your keyboard

Then respond with `Y` to confirm

Answer (score 0):

It seems that his happens when you don't have the images or fonts in your assets folder.

Since you use laravel-mix, you can just disable fetiching assets with:

```
mix.options({
    processCssUrls: true
});
```

Or make sure that they are in the assets folder.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/228#issuecomment-284076792) for more.